# What is this: \My\Namespace\MyClass::class?

Tags: php, class, constants

Can't seem to find any info about this.

```
\My\Namespace\MyClass::class
```

It returns the full class name, which is really really useful for what I'm currently doing, but where are the docs about it?

Is it a PHP 7 thing?

Comment: Namespacing has been around since PHP 5.3

Comment: Not namespacing, the `::class` constant.

Comment: http://php.net/oop5.basic#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Comment: That's been since PHP >= 5.5.0

Comment: @watcher yes, that's it. Post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **PHP 5.5** you can use class name resolution using `Some\Namespace\ClassName::class` notation

```
<?php
namespace Name\Space;
class ClassName {}

echo ClassName::class;
```

More info here http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name